# Processing a list of rx.Observables

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I want to process a `List<Observable<MyResponse>>`. How can I do this?
Had a look at Observable.zip() but unable to arrive at a conclusion.
Code snippet of what I wanna do:

```
List<String> myList = myMethod(); // myMethod() returns a List<String> of any possible length.
List<Observable<MyResponse>> observables = new ArrayList<>();
for (String value : myList) {
observableList.add(myAPI.getData(value))
} 
// How to? : For each Observable<MyResponse> in observables call a method myProcessor(MyResponse, ...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried again & the following worked for me:

```
List<Observable<MyResponse>> observables = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> values = getValues();
for (String value : values) {
    observables.add(myAPI.myMethod());
}
Observable.zip(observables, new FuncN() {
        @Override
        public Object call(Object... args) {
            for (Object arg : args) {
                process((MyResponse(arg));
            }
            return null;
        }
    }).toBlocking().first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `flatMap` the `myList`:

```
Flowable.fromIterable(myList)
    .flatMap(value -> myAPI.getData(value))
    .doOnNext(myResponse -> { /* ... */ })
    ...
```